# Date Parse / TypeError in django

Tags: python, django

there!

I've been trying to get over this bug for a little bit now, I've searched stackoverflow and found VERY similar posts, but none of the suggest solutions worked for me.

This is the error I get in the console:

```
(pyblog) SATCHELs-MacBook-Pro:src satchel$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, posts, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying posts.0002_post_updated...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 229, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 111, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1461, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1440, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1296, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1399, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/Users/satchel/Desktop/py/webground/pyblog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 93, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

This is my model.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
#from django.utils import


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs = {"id": self.id})
        #return "/posts/%s/"(self.id)
```

From similar questions I'm guessing it has something to do with the DateTimeField and problems parsing whatever arguments I've given it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you already have data in the timestamp field that isn't datetime?

Comment: @FeFiFoFu Nope, deleted all my data and tried again. No luck.

Comment: I ran your model.py in a new project and new database and it worked fine.

Comment: @FeFiFoFu How'd you go about it? I tried deleting all the posts through admin, and wiping the migrations folder (for which I just get no changes detected)

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up renaming my migrations folder, making a new one, and then running the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations posts
python manage.py migrate posts
```

Thanks @FeFiFoFu, your tip lead me to the right path